# Output high-resolution figure from Matlab with full picture

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to output a high-resolution figure from Matlab.
I tried to "save as pic.eps". But when I insert this picture in latex, it seems that the picture is not "real eps" in the sense that I can tell that the resolution is not enough.
I also tried to "save as pic.pdf". The resolution meets my demand, but the pic is cropped, as it is too large.

Then I used

```
 print -depsc -tiff -r300 -painters pic.eps
```

This gives me the high-resolution full picture, but some of the dashed lines in the original picture disappeared. I have tried many other cases and still couldn't find the right way to solve my problem. Any suggestions are highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try to save eps in **vector** format, or use a vector only format such as .svg.

For example,

```
print -depsc2 -painters test.eps
```

These are the vector graphics supported formats according to the current documentation:

```
Option      Vector Graphics Format                                  File Extension
'-dpdf'     Full page Portable Document Format (PDF) color          .pdf
'-deps'     Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) Level 3 black and white   .eps
'-depsc'    Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) Level 3 color             .eps
'-deps2'    Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) Level 2 black and white   .eps
'-depsc2'   Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) Level 2 color             .eps
'-dmeta'    Enhanced Metafile (Windows® only)                       .emf
'-dsvg'     SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics)                          .svg
'-dps'      Full-page PostScript (PS) Level 3 black and white       .ps
'-dpsc'     Full-page PostScript (PS) Level 3 color                 .ps
'-dps2'     Full-page PostScript (PS) Level 2 black and white       .ps
'-dpsc2'    Full-page PostScript (PS) Level 2 color                 .ps
```

you'll also have to use the `'-painters'` renderer  when saving vector graphics files. If you save to a vector graphics file and if the figure RendererMode property is set to 'auto', then print automatically attempts to use the Painters renderer. If you want to ensure that your output format is a true vector graphics file, then specify the Painters renderer. For example:

```
 print('-painters','-deps','myVectorFile')
```

Comment: I tried this `print -depsc2 -painters test.eps`, still, some of the dashed lines in the original picture disappear. I will try svg

Comment: what matlab version are you using?

Comment: also, this might be helpful... https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex

Comment: I am using Matlab R2018a

Comment: I recall earlier matlab versions (2014 or earlier) that had these issues exactly, and there were some file exchange codes that were suppose to address that (export_fig and such). I used to save as svg and then use inkscape to convert to eps, but now can use svg directly in latex...

Comment: you can also try other vector formats... (I edited the answer)

Comment: I am still dealing with this problem. I feel that it may be because my computer did not install some packages. Because after I export the pic.eps, it is quite large, e.g., 1.2 mb. Then Include this  pic.eps into latex, and compile it. Then it automatically generates a pic-eps-converted-to.pdf file, which is only 450k.

Comment: is your figure a graph of a photo? in other words, does it make sense to vectorize the image or maintain it's vecotor graphics nature? otherwise save to png, and use that in latex+pdf

Answer (score 0):

this command in question may come from the following [link](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92521-why-does-matlab-not-export-eps-files-properly)

After removing -tiff, my issue of missing one line was fixed (even though I don't understand what is '-tiff' for)